# Allow Changes to a Folder with Disk Protection Enabled - Windows SteadyState

Tags: windows, windows-xp, kiosk, steadystate

I've been using Windows SteadyState to keep my computers locked down in an office environment.  The tools my users need to do their jobs are available using a browser.  I've locked the machines down with Windows Disk Protection and I like how things are going with this.

Lately, I've decided to have one of our tools write a log to the HDD and I'd like to make the folder it uses "protected" from write protection.

I know I could have it save the log to a different partition or physical drive, but the machines don't have another partition yet and I don't want to have to image them all if I don't have to.

I know one of you has some good experience with Windows SteadyState and can help me.

How do I allow changes to a specific folder on a drive that's write-protected by Windows Disk Protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/windowssteadystate/thread/8abf2569-bd3a-418d-a7a0-6d9ba446c6bd) on the Microsoft SteadyState forums:

> Sean Zhu -Microsoft Contingent Staff, Moderator
>
> "I'd like to inform you that we cannot set exception in Windows Disk Protection in Windows SteadyState UI. If you have a second partition, the only workaround is putting it in the non-system partition. Thank you."

This puts my question to rest with a resounding "*It's not possible*".